# You need to add an icon to your APK-file

Tags: android, eclipse, icons

I'm trying to upload my application to the Google Play store, and everytime I try it, it says that I have to add an icon to it. I programmed that in my AndroidManifest file, with an working image. It still says that i have to add an icon to my APK file.

This is my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

If I need to add any other code, feel free to ask. I really need help, thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.rodekruis"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:icon="@drawable-hdpi/rkzpictogram.jpg">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
             android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.MAINACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".BezoekActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_bezoek" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.BEZOEKACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AfspraakActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_afspraak" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.AFSPRAAKACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ContactActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_contact" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.CONTACTACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MeningActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_mening" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.MENINGACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RouteActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_route" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.ROUTEACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SpecialistenActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_specialisten" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.SPECIALISTENACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".BWCActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_bwc" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.BWCACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AgendaActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_agenda" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.AGENDAACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".InfoActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_informatie" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.INFOACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".VriendActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_vriend" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.VRIENDACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".FoldersActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_folders" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.FOLDERSACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".NieuwsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_nieuws">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.example.rodekruis.NIEUWSACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: If  you are asking about Android you absolutely **must** specify the [tag:android] tag, Eclipse is used for many other things.

Comment: Yes, i'm talking about android. sorry about that

Comment: Do you have an answer to this?

Comment: No, I am an expert on Eclipse, not Android.

Comment: But can you see some mistakes in my manifest file, something with my icon code? If not, okay then, thanks anyway..

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, although I had just uploaded a build from the same app a few hours prior. My problem was solved by going to Build > Rebuild Project(In Android Studio), the apk I generated afterwards was uploaded successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you actually have an image file at `src/main/res/com/drawable-hdpi/rkzpictogram.jpg` then reference it in the `AndroidManifest.xml` with `@drawable-hdpi/rkzpictogram` (leave off the `.jpg` extension).  You may be able to use `@drawable/rkzpictogram` without the -hdpi extension as well.